# propagate CSS grid sizes to grandchildren for vuetify v-card image

Tags: css, vuetify.js, css-grid

I'm trying to arrange vuetify cards with images in a css grid, but the grid size isn't seen by the v-card's v-img since its a grandchild. How Can I propagate grid size down to the v-img?

I want the images to fill out out the card, similar to how the flex-box version looks (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#grids)

This is the look I'm going for, automatically resizing the image based on window size.

[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({})
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px - 60px);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grandchild {}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.2.26/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.2.26/dist/vuetify.min.css" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app fixed dark>
      <v-toolbar-title>Toolbar</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <div class="grid">
          <v-card v-for="n in 4" :key="n">
            <v-img height="100%" width="100%" class="grandchild" src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/docks.jpg">
            </v-img>

            <v-card-subtitle>Number {{ n }}</v-card-subtitle>
          </v-card>

        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer app dark>
      <span>Footer</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean  "fill out out the card" ? img has an fixed width on code.

Comment: sorry, I was just trying to keep the grid shape visible. I changed it to 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using 1fr on your layout. try to use `minmax(0, 1fr)` instead:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: calc(100vh - 64px - 60px);
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: just had to add `height: calc(100% - 54px)` to the `v-img` to get the `v-card-subtitle` to show up

Comment: Of course! I found this tweet that help me to understand use of  fr: https://twitter.com/wesbos/status/1256229763225657348/photo/1